# C++ Name Mangling - Back Reference

Tags: c++, visual-studio, compiler-construction, name-mangling

i have some difficulties understanding back reference in the case below.

for my understanding there is 2 groups of classes here:

1. ActionMetaData@Wrapper@@
2. ?$basic_string@_WU?$char_traits@_W@std@@

How can i tell which group this reference point to?

> @@1@@

```
"??0ActionMetaData@Wrapper@@QAE@ABV?$basic_string@_WU?$char_traits@_W@std@@V?$allocator@_W@std@@1@@0W4e_SDKTokenDataType@@W4e_SDKTokenType@@@Z"
```

for what i can see it points to char_traits.
but if i add the back reference 1 to

> 0W4e_SDKTokenDataType@1@W4e_SDKTokenType@1@

it will point to Wrapper

Comment: Have you tried using the `undname` utility that comes with visual studio?   It's stated purpose is to "convert a decorated name to its undecorated form",  where the word "decorated" means the representation used by the compiler i.e. in C++, the mangled name.

Comment: im using https://demangler.com/
but still i cant understand how the compiler can tell the difference

Comment: Perhaps [this reference about the MSVC++ mangling](https://en.wikiversity.org/wiki/Visual_C%2B%2B_name_mangling) could help helpful?